# How to email record as pdf to user with Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Based my previous question regarding a [document merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146043/document-merge-with-google-app-maker) I have created template. The template is stored in a shared folder or a team drive that is not directly accessible to the user. Whenever a user initiates a document merge, I would like the resulting PDF to be stored in the team drive and a copy to be emailed to the user. This way administrators don't need to create a copy for themselves as it is already stored in the team drive.

As I don't have Cloud SQL, I cannot access the App Maker PDF example that was released last month. But maybe someone can explain to me how I can find a solution for my requirements without Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the sample mentioned in the question for people who have Cloud SQL configured: [Email PDF Sample](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/email-pdf/). Just in case here are key code lines from the sample assuming that you already know [how to send email](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/email/) (this one should work without Cloud SQL) and [build a Doc from a record(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146043):

```javascript
var tmpDoc = createDocFromRecord(record);

var blob = tmpDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

pdfFile.setName(FILE_NAME);

// sendEmail_(to, subject, body)
sendEmail_(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), FILE_NAME, pdfFile.getUrl());
```